# Squared distance between two square-integrable functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I am working on a problem with functional PCA (AKA [Kosambi–Karhunen–Loève theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosambi%E2%80%93Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem)), and I'm having trouble reproducing a result from a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11081-021-09677-1#Sec6).

Let $ y(t) \;\; t\in [0,T]$ with mean $\mu_{fpca}(t)$ and covariance

$$k_{pca}(s,t) \equiv  \text{Cov}\{Y(s), Y(t)\}  = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \tau_k \Psi_k(s) \Psi_k(t)$$

where $\tau_1 \geq \tau_2 \geq \dots$ are eigenvalues and $\Psi_1(t), \Psi_2(t), \dots$ are the orthonormal vectors.

Our function $y(t)$ can be represented as:

$$ y(t) = \mu_{fpca}(t) +   \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \tau_k^{1/2} \beta_k \Psi_k(t) $$

where $\beta^i_k = \tau_k^{1/2}\int_{0}^T y_i(t)\Psi_k(t)dt$ is the kth principal component score.

The following result is where I get stuck. Given that the eigenvectors $\Psi_k$’s are orthonormal, the squared distance between any two square-integrable function $y_i(t)$ and $y_j(t)$ can be simplified to

$$\lVert y_i(t) - y_j(t)\rVert^2_2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \tau_k ( \beta^i_k - \beta^j_k)^2 dt$$

Any ideas on how to derive this result? I was thinking it might have something to do with the Cauchy product, but I'm not sure.